# Extracting subnets from nets.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, nets

Let $x_i:\Lambda_i\to X_i$ be a net in a topological spaces $X_i$ that converges to $a_i\in X_i$ where $i\in\{1,2\}$

Does there exist a poset $\Lambda$ and subnets of $x_i:\Lambda_i\to X_i$ of the form $y_i:\Lambda\to X_i$ ?

You can take a look at [this notes](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/254a-notes-8-a-quick-review-of-point-set-topology/) to remind definitions of net and especially of a subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the simple construction $\Lambda = \Lambda_1 \times \Lambda_2$ with the partial order

$$(\alpha,\beta) \leqslant (\gamma,\delta) \iff \alpha \leqslant \gamma \land \beta \leqslant \delta,$$

and $y_i = x_i \circ \pi_i$,  where $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th component.

In a given situation with known $\Lambda_i$, it is likely that one can construct more interesting index sets and subnets, but without any specific data, I don't see a way to produce something interesting.

Comment: I just came to delete my question since I come to exactly this solution :) but you beat me to this